# Rudin RCA ch. 1 ex. 5: Prove these sets are mesurable

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> **5** (a) Suppose $f:X\rightarrow[-\infty,\infty]$ and $g:X\rightarrow[-\infty,\infty]$ are measurable. Prove that the sets
> $$\{x:f(x)<g(x)\},\ \{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$$
> are measurable.
>
> (b) Prove that the set of points at which a sequence of measurable real-valued functions converges (to a finite limit) is measurable.

(a) Arrange the rational numbers in a sequence $\{x_n\}$. Since
$$\{x:f(x)<g(x)\}=\bigcup_n\{x:f(x)<x_n\}\cap\{x:x_n<g(x)\}\text{,}$$
it is measurable. By symmetry, $\{x:f(x)<g(x)\}$ is also measurable. Hence $\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$ being the complement of $\{x:f(x)\not=g(x)\}$ is measurable.

(b) Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real-valued functions. Put
$$g=\liminf f_n,\qquad h=\limsup f_n$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then $g$ and $h$ are measurable. We want to show that the set
$$\{x:-\infty<g(x)=h(x)<\infty\}$$
is measurable. By (a) $\{x:g(x)=h(x)\}$ is measurable. Thus
$$\{x:-\infty<g(x)=h(x)<\infty\}=\{x:g(x)=h(x)\}\cap\{x:-\infty<g(x)<\infty\}\cap\{x:-\infty<h(x)<\infty\}$$
is mesurable.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your are completely ignoring the possibility if $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ being $\pm \infty$.

Comment: $[-\infty,x_n)$ is open in $[-\infty,\infty]$, so $f^{-1}([-\infty,x_n))$ is measurable.